# Relação N x N em objetos Java

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, relacionamento

Tenho uma tabela item

```
(item_id (pk), descrição, ...),
```

Uma tabela fornecedor

```
(fornecedor_id (pk), nome, ...)
```

e por ser uma relação NxN tenho uma tabela intermédia item_fornecedor

```
(item_id (fk), fornecedor_id (fk), codigo, ...).
```

Como é que crio estes 3 objectos em Java (correspondentes a cada tabela), tendo em conta este relacionamento?

Comment: Está usando Hibernate?

Comment: Essas anotações são fornecidas como?

Comment: Não estou a usar JPA. Qual a solução alternativa?

Answer (score 0):

Vou compartilhar uma solução com você.

Vai precisar só acertar alguns detalhes como nome de campos fazer os get e set e os metodos hashcode e equals das 4 classes

Classe Item

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "item_id", length = 20, precision = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private Long            id;

    @Column(name = "descricao")
    private String          descricao;

    //implementar os metodos corretamente hashCode equals, recomendavel

}
```

Classe fornecedor

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "forncedor")
public class Fornecedor {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "forncedor_id", length = 20, precision = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private Long            id;

    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String          nome;

    //implementar os metodos corretamente hashCode equals, recomendavel

}
```

Classe da relação, os campos da relação devem ser iguais e mais **Devem ser igual ao DDL da tabela**

```
@Table(name = "item_fornecedor")
@IdClass(ItemFornecedorPk.class)
public class ItemFornecedor {

    private ItemFornecedorPk    pk;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id_pk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Item        item;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "forncedor_id_pk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Fornecedor          fornecedor;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "campoSoDaRelacao")
    private Date            campoSoDaRelacao;

    //implementar os metodos corretamente hashCode equals, obrigatório

}
```

Classe da chave da relacão

```
@Embeddable
public class ItemFornecedorPk {


    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "forncedor_id_pk", referencedColumnName = "forncedor_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Fornecedor      fornecedor;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id_pk", referencedColumnName = "item_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Item        item;

    //implementar os metodos corretamente hashCode equals, obrigatório
}
```

Agora é colocar para a factory ou o pesistyUnit ler e já funciona. da fazer as lista também no pai de cada um, mas ai só se precisar.